# When the network image is cached with the cached_network_image package does the image cached temporary or permanent?

Tags: flutter, image

I'm using the cached network image package i was wondering if the image that is cached is temporary cached or it will be deleted automatically at a certain of time, because i want it to be permanent

Answer (score 1):

from [Flutter Cache Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) which is the package Cached_network_image builds on top of

> When are cached files removed?  The files can be removed by the cache
> manager or by the operating system. By default the files are stored in
> a cache folder, which is sometimes cleaned for example on Android with
> an app update.
>
> The cache manager uses 2 variables to determine when to delete a file,
> the maxNrOfCacheObjects and the stalePeriod. The cache knows when
> files have been used latest. When cleaning the cache (which happens
> continuously), the cache deletes files when there are too many,
> ordered by last use, and when files just haven't been used for longer
> than the stale period.